# Function columns Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I am strugling with something probably easy in python/pandas...

I have a dataFrame with in columns dates, in index fruit names and inside, prices.

I am looking for a function which, when I input a date, give me the prices of my fruits for this date.

```
[in]  mylist
[out]

             2017-03-23 2017-03-22 2017-03-21 2017-03-20 2017-03-17 2017-03-16 

pear            12       13        14        12        20      17   
apple           14        9        11        21        12      4   
banana         120       180       140       170       605     802  
etc...         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN     NaN   


ex. [in] myPrice('2017-03-23')
[out]   2017-03-23
pear       12
apple      14 
banana     120
```

Thank you very much!

Edit: my goal is to enter a date and it gives me back the coresponding column, so 
    date = '2017-03-23'
    myPrice(date)
    return the corresponding.

so I am not trying to do it by mylist[2017-03-23] but with something who should be mylist[date]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need if columns are strings:

```
mylist['2017-03-23']
mylist.loc[:, '2017-03-23']
```

If columns are datetimes then need `datetime`:

```
#If columns not datetime, convert them
mylist.columns = pd.to_datetime(mylist.columns)

#convert string to datetime
date = pd.to_datetime('2017-03-23')
#another solution
#date = pd.Timestamp('2017-03-23')

print (mylist[date])
pear       12
apple      14
banana    120
Name: 2017-03-23 00:00:00, dtype: int64

print (mylist.loc[:, date])
pear       12
apple      14
banana    120
Name: 2017-03-23 00:00:00, dtype: int64
```

And for one column `DataFrame` add `[]`:

```
print (mylist[[date]])
        2017-03-23
pear            12
apple           14
banana         120

print (mylist.loc[:, [date]])
        2017-03-23
pear            12
apple           14
banana         120
```

Also works (but I get warning):

> VisibleDeprecationWarning: converting an array with ndim > 0 to an index will result in an error in the future
>     block = self.blocks[self._blknos[i]]

```
date ='2017-03-23'
print (mylist[date])
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I want it by entering the date in the function. 

Like 
    Myprice(date) 
    date =  '2017-03-23'

Then return the corresponding column

Comment: then just define `myPrice = lambda date: mylist.loc[:, date]`

Comment: It gives back <function __main__.<lambda>>

Comment: what return print (df.columns) ?

Comment: DatetimeIndex([ with my differents dates inside

Comment: So `date = pd.to_datetime('2017-03-23')`

`print (mylist[date])` or `print (mylist.loc[:, date])` can works perfectly

Comment: That was a lot of work.  You deserve more up votes :-)

Comment: @user6457870 - so key was no `datetime` ?

Comment: No, actually both of your answers were correct, I had just some small problems in my dataset... As a beginer some simple things looks hard when you never done it...

Comment: To finish I am trying to do something else, was wondering if there is a shortcut to do it. I want to find the percentile of each of this prices regarding all the prices for a date. I know how mathematically do it but I cant find anything to do it quickly... any idea? 

Thank you again!

Comment: It seems you need `print (mylist.quantile())`, also check [`quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html). If need something else, the best is create new question with sample data, desired output and what you try.

Answer (score 3):

`pandas` allows you to access columns via the column name with the `[]` selector

```
mylist['2017-03-23']
```

However, to be more explicit, you can use `.loc[]`

```
mylist.loc[:, '2017-03-23']
```

Or even use the `xs` method:

```
mylist.xs('2017-03-23', axis=1)
```

Any one of these could be wrapped in a fuction:

```
def myPrice(date):
    return mylist[date]
```

Comment: Thank you for your coment, unfortunately when I am doing that, it return 

TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index

Comment: @user6457870 sorry, there was a typo.  I had `data` instead of `date` in the function.  Try again